# converting C code to .gba with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

You know how you can compile C/C++ code into a .exe file
like this:

> g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe

Is it possible to compile C/C++ code to any other file format such as .gba using mingw?

Comment: .gba, as in a homebrew rom for a gameboy advanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in general, this is called "[cross compiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compile)". You're running windows, but you want binary code for a target system other than windows, like .gba.

The answer is yes, [gcc](http://cowlark.com/2009-07-04-building-gcc/), even the [mingw flavor of gcc](http://mingw.org/wiki/HostedCrossCompilerHOWTO) can be set up to build towards a target platform.

If you're specifically trying to do the homebrew thing for Nintendo's Gameboy Advanced, then no not really. [What you want is over here](http://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/setup.htm). It looks like they use something like mingw, but not quite.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. This helped alot. I'll look into it.

Comment: +1 for that tonc link. I remember having to create a couple GBA games at school with that.